# Potty Training round 1000, help!

Tags: toddler, potty-training

My almost 3-year old daughter was doing so well with potty training up until the lockdown 2 months ago. She had a serious regression, where she would take off her diaper and soil on the floor quietly... I've tried not to add pressure and have given her a complete break for about a month. I got her some stickers and a chart this weekend and tried to start getting her excited again, but it's not working- she still tells me no. I just ordered a tub of chocolate-covered raisins that should be arriving on Wednesday, and I will try again with that... clearly I am desperate :) 
Does anyone have any tips, it's hard not to add pressure because she isn't necessarily having accidents, she will intentionally go to her corner and remove her diaper to do her thing.

One other sort of related question, we were going to start transitioning her to a toddler bed since she's climbing out from her crib a lot more. Should I hold off and do one thing at a time?

Thank you in advanced... with everything going on in the world, it's hard to feel helpless even in your own home! 
Sending good vibes to everyone!

**Update:** We have gone the naked route at home and that she's now been going to the restroom on her own for the past 3 days with minimal accidents (at bedtime we are still using pull-ups for now)!! I would like to introduce underwear again at home instead of just nude, but I am afraid she's going to think it's similar to diapers and just forget the potty. Maybe I am overthinking it.

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely do one thing at a time. Does she consistently go to the same corner? Could you have a child potty in that corner? Or multiple potties in multiple corners?If she knows when to go but she’s not doing it where you want maybe there’s some thing about that location that she does not like, maybe it’s too far. maybe she’s afraid of the flush? Or maybe if she involves you she feels pressure and if she goes quietly she can take her on time?

Comment: Thanks so much for responding! I will definitely stick to doing one thing at a time, you’re absolutely right! She doesn’t stick just with one corner, it’s kind of just anywhere to be honest.. this morning she came into the bathroom and did it right in front of the toilet while I was brushing my teeth :/

Answer (score 2):

> She had a serious regression, where she would take off her diaper and
>   soil on the floor quietly

Well, she's learned not to go in her diaper, which is good.  She has the basic principle.

Does she have her own potty, or is she using the toilet?  Maybe she has sensory issues around the toilet?  Too big, or too uncomfortable, or too loud when it flushes?

My kid was potty trained by just having her sit on it and chatting until something happened.  Maybe a couple days of doing sessions like this a few times a day will teach her that going on the potty is fine.  Certainly, you should teach her that she has to help clean when she goes on the floor, but you will handle the potty.

Comment: She's been using the big toilet with a smaller seat attachment for her.. This week I've been pretty low key about it and have been mainly bribing her with a reward if she uses it.. which has worked (she still has a couple of accidents)..but she's not fighting me anymore.. although I don't know how long that'll last! Yesss thank you for the tip about helping with cleanup!!